Frequency-wavenumber spectrum using FFT-Burg
I am trying to use hybrid frequency-wavenumber spectrum estimation methods to estimate frequency-wavenumber spectrum of acoustic data acquired using distributed sensors. The technqiue that I am using is FFT-Burg method which implements Fast Fourier Transform of the acquired data in time dimension and Burg (Maximum Entropy Method) in space dimension.The purpose of using this approach is to improve wavenumber resolution of the frequency-wavenumber spectrum because the data is acquired using limited number of sensors. I used the technqiue described in this paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6587/abe024). In this technique, FFT is used to convert the data from sapce-time domain to space-frequency domain. The resulting array is 2D array of complex numbers. Then Burg method is used to convert data (complex array) from space-frequency domain to frequency-wavenumber domain.  Despite I got frequency-wavenumber spectrum with higher resolution and lower background noise as shown in the first figure, I find that the peaks in the spectrum which corresponds to the speed of acoustic waves are shifted compared with the actual values as shown in the second figure. Is there any reason for that? Am I missing a correction that should be made before using Burg method  

Do you have any data you can upload?

Baddioes Yes, I can upload the synthetic data set used for the above plots.

@Baddioes
Are you still want me to share the data?

Sure, I'll see what I'm able to do with it.

@Baddioes
How can I share the data with you?

Can you place a link to the data in your original post?
